# In 1.18.1 is the mob generation different for my mob farms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In 1.18.1 is the mob generation different for my mob farms? Like different from 1.16 and 1.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, no.

According to [1.18.1 Minecraft changelog](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/minecraft-java-edition-1-18-1), changes were applied to fog:

> World fog now starts further away from the player, to make distant terrain more visible.
> Instead of applying fog as a spherical volume, it is now applied as a cylindrical volume.

And of course, several bugs were fixed. But nothing regarding mob spawn.

Latest version to change mobs spawn was [1.18](https://www.sportskeeda.com/minecraft/mob-spawning-changes-minecraft-1-18-all-need-know):

> - Axolotls can now only spawn in the water above clay blocks in lush cave biomes.
> - Cod, dolphins, pufferfish, salmon, squid, and tropical fish will only spawn in water between height levels Y=50 and Y=64. However, these creatures can spawn in lush cave biomes' water at any height.
> - Drowned zombies can now spawn in dripstone cave biomes and warm ocean biomes.
> - Pillagers can now spawn on snow blocks.
> - Foxes can now spawn on podzol, snow, and coarse dirt blocks.
> - Glow squids now only spawn in water blocks under the height level Y=30.
> - Goats may now only spawn in snowy slope, jagged peaks, and snowy peak mountain biomes.
> - Rabbits can now spawn on snow blocks.
> - Wolves can now spawn on snow blocks.
> - Hostile mobs now spawn only in areas where the block light level is equal to zero.